# django redirect url with parameter

Tags: python, django

when user click `make thumbnail`button ,it will call `def thumb`in the view 
and then render to  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/thumb`

I want to change to redirect to the url with the `id number` in database(Item.objects.all()) like :
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/thumb/123`

But not get it. 
Please help me.Thank you very much.

My code:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^$', views.background, name='background'),
    url(r'^thumb/(?P<result>\d+)$', views.thumb, name='thumb'),
```

views.py

```
def thumb(request,result):
    if request.method=="POST":
        photoid = request.POST['photoid']
        photowidth = request.POST['photowidth']
        item=Item.objects.filter(id=photoid) 
        return redirect(reverse('imageupload:thumb',kwargs={'result':photoid,'item':item }))

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload:background'))
```

templates:

```
  <form action="{% url 'imageupload:thumb'  i.id %}" method="POST" id="create_post">
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use kwargs={'item' : item} instead of args. Note, however, that if you're using named parameters in your url definition then your kwarg name will need to match. aka: kwargs={'result' : item}

Comment: I think in general, however, you might be a bit confused since the code doesn't seem to make a lot of sense and there are several problems. Rather than posting a bunch of code can you specify what it is you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

When you use named parameter, you need to do like this:

```
return redirect(reverse('imageupload:thumb',kwargs={'result':item}))
```

And in your `forms.py`, you also need to modify your `action` to this:

```
action="{% url 'imageupload:thumb' result %}"
```

You can also access `result` in `views.py` like this:

```
def thumb(request, result):
    print result
```